# Docusign Composite Template - Text Tabs / Prefilled Field

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I have an envelope that is comprised of 5/6 templates with various fields within each of the documents that need to be populated.  Many of these are marked by a string that I want to replace such as $$string-to-replace$$.  The values for these are pulled from a db.

My first thought was to do this with prefilled tabs but I got an error that I couldn't have PrefilledTabs within a recipient definition, so I moved to TextTabs.  Example code shown below:

```
Text text = new Text
            {
                FontSize = "size12",
                FontColor = "black",
                Locked = "true",
                AnchorString = anchorStringValue.AnchorString,
                Value = anchorStringValue.AnchorValue
            };
textTabList.Add(text);
Tabs signerTabs = new Tabs {SignHereTabs = signHereList, TextTabs = textTabList};
signer.Tabs = signerTabs;
```

This somewhat works but the text underneath shows up underneath the value when it is placed using an anchor string. From another post I saw that this could be fixed by making the text in the templates white but that makes it hard for edits to be made in the future so I would like to avoid this if possible.

Ideally, I want to allow another member of my team to make the templates in the Docusign UI and then have labeled text fields that I can replace using the docusign api / code.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: can you make the anchor string white on white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acutally I figured out what I wanted to do. I can assign Roles to the template fields that I add (checkbox, text, etc.) in the UI.  And then in the API when I assign signers to the envelope I can assign them the Role I specified in the template. Hope this helps someone in the future

[image]

[image]

You can update the text in the textbox's etc like this

```
    Text inlcudedOnTemplateTest2 = new Text
    {
        TabLabel = "test_text2",
        Value = "TESTING TEXTBOX 2",
        Locked = "true"
    };
```

And you can assign that role to each signer like this

```
        Signer signer = new Signer
        {
            Email = "####email####",
            Name = "####Name####",
            RecipientId = "1",
            RoutingOrder = "1",
            RoleName = "Signer"
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Make the anchor string white, invisible. They will still be found.
2. Don't use anchor string, but fixed positioning if you know where the tabs should be placed.

Comment: HI Inbar, thanks for the response. Can the tabs be added/put into position in the template document using the UI and then edited through the api?

Comment: I guess my question is whether or not I can put a "holder" textbox (not assigned to any specific signer/recipient) and then fill that in using the API

Comment: Currently the feature called pre-filled tabs (or pre-filled fields) is not available for templates. You can do it with an envelope that was created from a template using the API

Comment: hmm i think that would lead to a similar result as what I had originally asked thanks

Comment: It doesnt seem to give me the flexibility that I am wanting... maybe I will reach out to docusign support to see if they have any other idea

Comment: You indicated your issue was that the fields were visible on the document, and you didn't want them to show. I explained how to avoid this.

Comment: If that's not what your issue is - I'm not clear what is the problem

Comment: this second part -- "Ideally, I want to allow another member of my team to make the templates in the Docusign UI and then have labeled text fields that I can replace using the docusign api / code"

Comment: You can do this with envelopes, these members of your team can then add pre-filled fields (drag and drop) to the envelope and then you can use API to update their values